# How to get next element in for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

In a dataset I have different locators. Some places are free (locator = null). I would like to capture these and push them into arrays.

In the subarray may only be locations that are in a row. If a distance is greater than 1 then it comes to the next array.

```
const freeLocs = locs.filter(elem => !elem.locator)

let temp = []
let array2D = []

for(let i = 0; i < freeLocs.length-1; i++) {    

   let abs = Math.abs(freeLocs[i+1].position - freeLocs[i].position)
 
   temp.push(freeLocs[i])

   if(abs > 1) {
       array2D.push(temp)
     temp = []
   } 

}

console.log(array2D)
```

Now I have the problem that the last array is not filled.

https://jsfiddle.net/5yk0mpt9/2/

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: How about changing the condition which handles the pushing and resetting of `temp` from `(abs > 1)` to `((abs > 1) || ((i === freeLocs.length - 1) && temp.length))` or something similar for I only can make a sophisticated guess about not loosing the remaining/unpushed `temp` data at the last iteration step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem starts here:

```
for(let i = 0; i < freeLocs.length-1; i++) {
```

with this condition you lose the last item of the array:

```
i < freeLocs.length-1
```

it needs to change like this:

```
i < freeLocs.length
```

but it also needs an extra check inside the loop before trying to get the

```
freeLocs[i + 1].position
```

for the last iteration

for example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < freeLocs.length; i++) {
  temp.push(freeLocs[i]);

  if (
    (i === freeLocs.length - 1) ||
    (Math.abs(freeLocs[i + 1].position - freeLocs[i].position) > 1)
  ) {
    array2D.push(temp)
    temp = [];
  }
}
```

working demo here: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6oyexnvb/4/)

Comment: I'm convinced that your approach nailed it (for it does cover the edge cases).